# mkfs -O ^64bit,^metadata_csum -t ext4 in 2019

Tags: filesystems, ext4

Thomas Krenn recommends creating ext4 partitions like:

https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/FSCK_Best_Practices

```
mkfs -O ^64bit,^metadata_csum -t ext4
```

what does this mean?

does this have anything to do with the y2038 problem?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

"A user should be able to turn on this feature at mke2fs time simply by specifying -O metadata_csum. Because the 64bit feature allows arbitrarily large block group descriptors that are large enough to enable crc32c for the bitmaps, mke2fs should warn the user if the feature set is metadata_csum,^64bit when it becomes the case that the 64bit feature has been tested thoroughly."

https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Metadata_Checksums

what is recommended? move to btrfs?

thanks!

Comment: Consider btrfs as dead or dying.

Comment: @Sven Agreed.  FWIW, BTRFS was [developed by Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs), IMO likely as a competitor to Sun's ZFS.  Well, Oracle bought Sun and now owns ZFS.  And [Red Hat dropped support of BTRFS in August 2017.](https://www.google.com/search?q=red+had+drops+btrfs)

Answer (score 4):

This is an excerpt from the kernel documentation for
`metadata_csum` and `64bit`:

> Starting in early 2012, metadata checksums were added to all major
>   ext4   and jbd2 data structures. The associated feature flag is metadata_csum.
>   The desired checksum algorithm is indicated in the superblock, though as of October 2012 the only supported algorithm is crc32c. Some data structures did not have space to fit a full 32-bit checksum, so only the lower 16 bits are stored. Enabling the 64bit feature increases the data structure size so that full 32-bit checksums can be stored for many data
>       structures. However, existing 32-bit filesystems cannot be extended to
>       enable 64bit mode, at least not without the experimental resize2fs
>       patches to do so.
>           Existing filesystems can have checksumming added by running `tune2fs -O metadata_csum` against the underlying device. If tune2fs encounters directory blocks that lack sufficient empty space to add a
>       checksum, it will request that you run `e2fsck -D` to have the
>       directories rebuilt with checksums. This has the added benefit of
>       removing slack space from the directory files and rebalancing the htree
>       indexes. If you ***ignore*** this step, your directories will not be
>       protected by a checksum!

Answer (score 3):

> what does this mean?

simple what you may run into compatibility troubles by using this features now (and they are the defaults for modern mkfs setup), so it's better to keep them off until explicitly requested 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/747656/ext4-broken-file-system-on-ubuntu-14-04-4 - good example (the author was naive enough to blindly follow some others instruction, not knowing what the commands do - so he seems lost all his disk instead of fixing it ;-)

> does this have anything to do with the y2038 problem?

nay, just turns off questionable additional features - one is not well-tested, second is depended of first but not enforces it (so kernel may crash someday), both breaks fsck on older platforms.

as for btrfs - you better try it yourself. Sometimes it fits well, sometimes redhat-enforced configurations with xfs+lvm suits better, sometimes it just doesn't worth the time - ext4 still "just works" for most common uses.

Comment: The linked example is just some guy trying to use these relatively new features with older tools that didn't support them. That is *not* a valid reason to avoid their use with up-to-date tools, and says nothing about the actual reliability of these features. As with all things IT, you need to know what you're doing - especially when dealing with important data, and before taking potentially destructive actions. And always have a backup.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to the other answers that specifically the syntax `mkfs -O ^64bit,^metadata_csum -t ext4` means "Create an ext4 filesystem with the `64bit` and `metadata_csum` features disabled."

See the [man page for `mkfs.ext4`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4).
The [ext4 man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html) briefly explains the features.