# Ext4 metadata checksums: current feature status

Tags: filesystems, ext4, data-integrity

The [kernel wiki page for ext4 metadata checksums](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Metadata_Checksums) is marked "last modified on 22 October 2013". I couldn't find more recent status information on this feature, except for [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/950704/616519) from 2019, which suggests to disable it and the related `64bit` feature. One of the answers there claims that the `64bit` feature "is not well-tested", but I'm not sure if that's correct. There was no basis quoted for that claim, and given the prevalence of 64-bit systems in recent years, it sounds questionable. I do know `metadata_csum` depends on `64bit` for full checksums.

**My question:**
As of 2020+, are these two related features (`metadata_csum` and `64bit`) considered stable and safe? How well tested are they, really? Are there any important bugs, gotchas, or failure modes that should be considered before enabling these?

Comment: Your systems *e2fsprogs* man pages (`man 8 tune2fs`) hopefully contain *much* more recent information than that (you can likely trust the userland programs to be paired with compatible kernel versions: the Debian maintainer is also kernel subsystem maintainer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A certain *Theodore Ts'o* has, back in in 2015, enabled both feature by default for filesystems created with version `e2fsprogs 1.43`. Before that, it was [only enabled when needed](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/commit/cd27af3ecb83e8fd1e3eaa14994284a1818c7c15).

> Mke2fs will now create file systems with the metadata_csum and 64bit
> features enabled by default. [e2fsprogs/doc/RelNotes/v1.43.0.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/master/doc/RelNotes/v1.43.0.txt)

That default having found its way into `Ubuntu 18.04` (that is the LTS release *before* the current one) should mean that at least in any setup  supported and used with Ubuntu, it is widely tested with kernel versions starting with `4.15`. **If there were serious issues left, we would know by now.**

Comment: example of a [noteworthy outstanding bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1805913) only affecting unusual setups

Answer (score 2):

`metadata_csum` should be stable, as it has found its way in RHEL8

`64bit` is the same; from [ext4 man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html):

> This feature is set automatically, as needed

Comment: That sounds outdated, see my answers. resize2fs *errors out* instead of setting it automatically, and mke2fs *unconditionally* uses the command line setting or the default instead of deferring to necessity.